# Windows Remote Assistance in LAN environment

Tags: windows-7, remote-assistance

Is it possible to configure Windows Remote Assistance so admin don't need an invitation request to remotely control a users screen (screen share style) to help them with helpdesk I.T. issues?

Both the user and the admin will be using Windows 7 in a LAN environment.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but the user will still have to grant you access.
You the admin needs to be in the group "Offer Remote Assistance Helpers" on the users computer (make that happen through a GPO).
Then you can simply push an assistance offer through the GUI of MS Remote Assistance or use this command line:

```
msra /offerra NameOfComputerWithUserInNeedOfHelp
```

Your user will be asked twice for permission, the first time for you to see and the second time for you to be able to do something.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to go the windows way, you can try [Dameware](http://www.dameware.com/).  It is a bit pricey, but it has the option to let you take total control of the user PC with or without user knowledge or intervention.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this can be done via Active Directory
Go to properties of the users Lan ID
uncheck the Require user's permission

That should do it..